SSRS report that resembles tiles, with each tile representing a separate record
I'm attempting to generate a report that resembles tiles, with each tile representing a separate record. However, I'm encountering an issue where the output appears as one continuous line instead of wrapping onto multiple lines per page. When I print the report, it only displays one line per page, which is not the format I intended. Is there a solution to achieve the desired layout? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
this is what I've tried:

My current result:

the output I am expecting (multiple lines per page)


I've attempted to put together a SSRS report that behaves the way you are describing. One way of building a report like this is called a Newsletter-Style Report.
Here is a StackOverflow discussion about this: How do I make a column in a report wrap and/or break in multi-column report?
To make this style of report, make a new tablix and give it one row group. The group expression should be set to a unique value associated with each of your tiles. In your case, it should be something like a person ID or possibly the CID column in your screenshots.


For that row group, add page breaking at the end of the group.

Open the properties for that group and under the page break section add this formula
=NOT ROWNUMBER("DataSet1") mod 5 = 0


The number 5 is the number of tiles in each column.
The "DataSet1" should be the name of the data set you are using to populate this report.
After that change the number of columns in your report properties in the Page > Columns section to 6. That is the number of tiles in each row.

That should give you something that fits multiple rows of tiles on each page. You may have to adjust the number of rows and columns to fit what you are making. Make sure that there are now gaps in the report canvas so it's easy to fit as many tiles as possible.
The only issue I am currently having is that this wraps the tiles first vertically, then horizontally. You may be expecting the other direction, but I hope this is useful for you.
Also, this only works for the layout/print/PDF view of the report. I understand that is what you are working on though.

Unchecking "Allow height to increase" for each row will keep each tile the same size.

I'm attaching an RDL I made to demo this. This is the first time I am sharing a RDL file like this, but it is pulling data from https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml, so anyone should be able to run this file in Visual Studio or the Report Builder without having to setup any connections or data. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Here is the example file https://file.io/kGokP6zym8oh
